# transcriptions of the OT and NT texts

Tags: hebrew

Can you advise where to find transcriptions (i.e. pronunciation, e.g. *dawar*; I don't mean transliteration - *dābār*) of the hebrew (OT) and greek (NT) texts?

Comment: 'Transcription' means just a 'copy'. [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/204650?redirectedFrom=transcription#eid). Are you looking for a phonetic representation of text ? [Phonetic copy.](https://tophonetics.com/).

Comment: See https://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/1-1.htm

Comment: @Dottard Why should Anne see that site?  That has the transliteration, but not the pronunciation--i.e. it. has exactly what she said she did not want.

Comment: @Biblasia - that is not true - every word is transliterated phonetically in its inflected form

Comment: @Dottard Just look at her example: _(i.e. pronunciation, e.g. dawar; I don't mean transliteration - dābār)_.  The word is NOT pronounced with a "B" sound--its actual pronunciation is with a soft "V"--but that is not what you get with a transliteration of the word, because the Hebrew letter is the _bet_, which transliterates to a "B".  This is not the pronunciation, it is the transliteration--which is what the OP does not want.  BibleHub is giving the transliteration, not the pronunciation.

Comment: No one knows for certain how they were pronounced. But in general, I would think that pronunciation information belongs in a grammar or dictionary of the language, rather than trying to phonetically transcribe the entire text.

Comment: I agree that the pronunciation of the ancient Hebrew is debated.  Many believe that word was actually pronounced "debar".  The Ashkenazi Jews pronounce it with a "v" sound and other use a different sound.

Comment: @Dottard The original pronunciation in English of words like _know, knot, knife, etc._ was like "ka-no", "ka-not", "ka-naif", etc.  Should a transliteration of these words into another language include the phoneme for the "k"?  As that pronunciation ceased to exist centuries ago and the "k" has been silent ever since, it is no longer necessary to include the "k" in pronunciation guides--but perhaps a _transliteration_ might still have it.  The same is true for Hebrew: it doesn't really matter how the language may have evolved--how it is pronounced _today_ is what the OP likely wants to know.